# How to make a part of Stringbuilder content bold?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stringbuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(
        string.Format("{0} |{1} ", Name, Value)
        );
Display.Text = sb.ToString();  // Display is a WP7 TextBlock control
```

I want to make "Name" as bold. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: StringBuilder just helps you construct a string.  It does not provide any formatting, unless the TextBlock control accepts special formatting characters (I'm not familiar with WP7 UI programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put the text into a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and have the name as a separate `Run` in the `Paragraph` as in this example from the MSDN:

```
// Create a Run of plain text and some bold text.
Run myRun1 = new Run();
myRun1.Text = "A RichTextBox with ";
Bold myBold = new Bold();
myBold.Inlines.Add("initial content ");
Run myRun2 = new Run();
myRun2.Text = "in it.";

// Create a paragraph and add the Run and Bold to it.
Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun1);
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myBold);
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun2);

// Add the paragraph to the RichTextBox.
MyRTB.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman According to the MSDN page it's supported - there's the phone icon against the methods etc. and the Version Information states "**Silverlight for Windows Phone** Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.1"

Comment: @ChrisF: RTB is a bit heavy for the basic requirement.

Answer (score 7):

ChrisF offers the `RichTextBox` as a solution but its less well known that simple font variation is acheivable with the simple `TextBlock:`-

```
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Hello " });
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "World", FontWeight= FontWeights.Bold });
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about that. It's even in my answer!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try with the Textblock !

Answer (score 3):

A `StringBuilder` only contains character data, not formatting. You can't, basically. Unless you are actually generating html or rtf etc.

In the same way that notepad.exe doesn't have bold/italics/etc.

I'm not a WP7 expert, but maybe there is a different control you can use here, more aimed at formatted text.