# Get text to be bold

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, stringbuilder

I have a function that creates a PDF with iTextSharp,

It will get each date in the datagridview, with the associated data that is connected to it, and put it in a PDF.

However, you cannot see that the dates are supposed to be headers, so my question is;

How can I make the dates bold or change the font size to a bit higher size, so you will see them as headers.

My code if it isn´t clear enough for you;

```
//I am using a stringbuilder, this is the place where I declare it
StringBuilder pdfData = new Stringbuilder();

//Here I go through each datetime, from point a (datetimePicker 1), to point b(datetimePicker 2)
for (DateTime dt = dtDateVanaf.Value; dt <= dtDateTot.Value; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
    //This is supposed to be a header text, I want this part to be bold or a larger font size
    pdfData.Append(dt.ToString("dddd dd MMM yyyy"));
    pdfData.Append("\n\n");

    //This is the part that I check the datagridview for the associated data foreach date time
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        //And so on...
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002687/how-to-make-a-part-of-stringbuilder-content-bold

Comment: Does this mean iTextSharp does not come with any manual or any kind of documentation at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text isn't just "bold" or "italic", you are actually seeing a different, although related, font when you are seeing these things (although faux bold and faux italic does technically exist).

So when you want to bold something, you need switch to a bold font. If you are controlling your fonts explicitly [then you can do that manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213836/231316) which will give you the most control. If you aren't specifying actual fonts and are leaving it up to system defaults then you can [generate very simple HTML and let the system take care of things for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327462/231316).